# How to dynamically change the background of a button

Tags: ios, image, button, swift

Trying to dynamically change a button image.

```
reloadStopButton.currentImage = UIImage(named: "logo0.png")
```

Throws...
 **Cannot assign to the result of this expression**

Grr.. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: Easy on the downvote people; now my account is locked. It's tough now, especially as Swift has just been released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the button image setter:

```
reloadStopButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "logo0.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Button's need to know which state you are setting something for. This matters for things like their `title`, `titleColor`, and `backgroundImage` too.

If you look at the docs for `currentImage` you will see it is a readonly property. It just returns which image is currently being displayed. This can be useful for if you have different images showing for different states.

Comment: tyvm. Still getting used to the syntax.